# what is preventing base64_decode from working for large files/images

Tags: php, image, post, base64, png

I have implemented three php scripts, two of which proposed on stackoverflow, to resolve an issue where base64_decode of larger images didn't work. At this point I have given up on the php script and am just wondering what server upgrade might be necessary to get it to work. All three work on one server with any resolution, but on another server the maximum resolution obtained is around 1680 x 800 (file size around 140 kb). Beyond this, it fails and it outputs an empty image (filesize 0 kb). The data is posted from a Flash app. the only difference I can see between the two servers is the php memory limit (256 MB vs 128 MB). Could this be it? Thanks for any suggestions!

The php scripts tried are copied below:

version 1:

```
$png = base64_decode($_POST['imagedata']);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['name']);
echo $png;
```

version 2:

```
$encoded = $_POST['imagedata'];
$decoded = ""; 
for ($i=0; $i < ceil(strlen($encoded)/256); $i++) 
$decoded = $decoded . base64_decode(substr($encoded,$i*256,256));    
header('Connection: Keep-alive');
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['name']);
echo $decoded;
```

version 3:

```
$data = $_POST['imagedata'];
$target = 'img_'.date('Y-m-d-H-s').'.png';

$whandle = fopen($target,'w');
stream_filter_append($whandle, 'convert.base64-decode',STREAM_FILTER_WRITE);

fwrite($whandle,$data);
fclose($whandle);
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($target));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($target));
readfile($target);
unlink($target);
```

Comment: Please add the html form or explain the way used to get the imagedata content.

Comment: the image data is posted from a Flash app

Comment: Can you capture the flash post data to a file to check if is captured correctly and has a correct b64 format.? Add the first and last 20 characters and the size (number of characters) for example. The B64 needs to have some rules to be correct. In case that data is not correct the base64_decode function returns a FALSE instead any data.

Comment: Well it works perfectly on one server but not another, and it works perfectly on both at lower resolutions...so this suggests the output is correct but it's a server limitation?

Answer (score 2):

Probably a memory related problem : post size limit or php memory usage limit.

- Check your scripts' memory consumption using xdebug : http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace. Your script should not exceed memory_limit parameter from your php.ini file : http://php.net/manual/fr/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit
- Check your php.ini for post_max_size (should be greater than your max image's size)
- Check if your web server has any limitation for post data.
- Check your logs : if base64_encode is not encoding properly, there should be an error message, somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! It's a client server so getting them to install xdebug may be tricky but hopefully they can. post_max_size is 55M (max image size is only around 140 kb). Is there any other post limitation that could cause this?

Comment: just confirmed that unfortunately the host doesn't support XDEBUG...is there any other way of checking memory usage?

Comment: I just used echo memory_get_usage() and it output "1,795,496" which is way lower than the 128 MB limit...so I guess the issue is neither post_max_size nor php memory limit?

Comment: it seems it might be suhosin.post.max_value_length

Comment: Maximum post size can be limited by web server (for intance for nginx : http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size).